# Azure vm scale set, scaling profile minimum instance limits meaning

Tags: azure, azure-vm-scale-set

I have created a vm scale set with scaling profile as below -

[image]

But if i go and delete instances in VM scaleset it is not scaling it back to 2.

PFB screenshot , why is it happening , is it expected behaviour , if yes what is the meaning of minimum number of instances?

[image]

Comment: yeah, i dont think it prevents you from deleting it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the instance limits just make sure you do not scale in beyond the minimum of instances, if you delete the instance manually, it will not scale back to 2.

The autoscale just happens when it meets the autoscale condition, for example, you deleted the instance, then the (Average)Percentage CPU > 75, the instances will return to 2. If the (Average)Percentage CPU < 25, it will auto scale to 2 at most, the `minimum` decided it. But if you delete the instance manually, it is not decided by `minimum`.

For more details, see [Define autoscale instance limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-autoscale-portal#define-autoscale-instance-limits).

Comment: I have seen in AWS autoscale group used to do that , but looks like azure scaling profile , doesn't do that.